# RegEx to match days hours minutes with spaces

Tags: regex

I need to make sure the users' time stamp input is
(0 to infinity) days
(0 to 23) hours
(h to 59) minutes

with spaces between, so good example is

- 22h 40m
- 2d 20m
- 1d

but not

- 0d
- 2d22h20m

what i have so far is:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*d)?( [0|[1-5][0-9]*h)?(0| [1-5][0-9]*m)?$
```

which gets:

- 22d 3h 40m
- 2d 40m

but not

- 40m
- 40h

it seems trivial, and I've composed it from several SO questions, but nothing matches exactly this.
**Edit**
just note that my original attempt has a mistake that allows 1-59 **hours**.

Comment: why 40m not accpeted ?

Comment: So you want to also match `40m` and `40h` separetely but not concatenated without a space? Perhaps you could specify all the formats that you would allow https://regex101.com/r/7LavKj/1

Comment: So what is a valid users' time stamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite verbose, but one option could be to use an alternation and list all the allowed possibilities using your patterns for d, h and m.

Matching (d h m) or (d h) or (d m) or (h m) or (d) or (h) or (m) you might use:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]*d (?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h (?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m|[1-9][0-9]*d (?:(?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h|(?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m)|(?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h (?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m|[1-9][0-9]*d|(?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h|(?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m)$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bDlPdH/1)

That will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[1-9][0-9]*d (?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h (?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m` Match full part
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9][0-9]*d` Match `d`
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h` Match `h`
    - `|` Or
    - `(?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m` Match `m`
  - `)`  close non capturing group
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h (?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m` Match `h` and `m`
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9][0-9]*d` Match `d`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h` Match `h`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:[1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m` Mach `m`
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

Comment: I upvoted it because it seems the only way is really to list all options. however, you took my mistake and extended it (allow 1-59 hours..). So i'll update my original question with a modified version of your answer

Comment: @yoadw Ah I see, I have updated it. You can prepend the 0 in an alternation accordingly if you want to match that as well for the hours.

Comment: can you edit again to include the hours-minutes pair and days only, and i'll mark yours selected answer? i think it is better structured and explaining than mine, even if mine is currently the correct one.

Comment: @yoadw I have updated my answer using your answer and created non capturing groups instead. Also I have used an alternation for the (d h) or (d m) part, matching `d` followed by either `h` or `m`

Answer (score 0):

Edit
The only suggestions (so far) are really to list all possibilities. So I'll be doing that here.. just note that my original attempt has a mistake that allows 1-59 hours.
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/frAFRL/1)

`^((([1-9][0-9])d (2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h ([1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m)|(([1-9][0-9])d (2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h)|(([1-9][0-9])d ([1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m)|((2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h ([1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m)|([1-9][0-9])d|(2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9])h|([1-5][0-9]|[1-9])m)$`

meaning: (d h m) or (d h) or (d m) or (h m) or (d) or (h) or (m)